# How to set shipping method without address in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I just wanted to give you the guidance that how we can set the shipping method without calculating shipping in cart page.

Answer (score 0):

We can have shipping charges added to total by calculating in shipping calculator - entering country,state & zip code....but without calculating it......is also possible.

Credit goes to this link :-
http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/

Why I am writing this....because this solution is hard to find.

Basically we need to create an observer which will observe the event....when we add any product to cart & it will directly add the given shipping method.

Thanks.